# Using the `==` operator on circularly defined dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, circular-reference

Python allows dictionaries to be compared with `==`

```
import copy

child = {'name': 'child'}
parent_1 = {'name': 'parent', 'child': child}
parent_2 = copy.deepcopy(parent_1)
print(parent_1 == parent_2)
```

Prints `True`, as you would expect it to.

Python also allows dictionaries to reference each other circularly.

```
child = {'name': 'child'}
parent_1 = {'name': 'parent', 'child': child}
child['parent'] = parent_1  # Create the circular reference
```

However, trying to use the `==` operator on dictionaries with circular references raises an error.

```
parent_2 = copy.deepcopy(parent_1)
print(parent_1 == parent_2)
```

Returns

```
C:\Python34\python.exe -i C:/Users/anon/.PyCharm40/config/scratches/scratch_5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/anon/.PyCharm40/config/scratches/scratch_5", line 11, in <module>
    print(parent_1 == parent_2)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

How can I check two dictionaries with circular references for equality?

Comment: I suspect the dictionaries are simply comparing each key/value pair and calling the equality method recursively on any dictionaries they find, creating an infinite loop.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Thank you for testing it.  What Python version are you using?  I am still getting the error with the above code.

Comment: I'm using python v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601. It works in 2.7.8 too.

Comment: tested on 3.4.0 and 2.7.6 => both got RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: You would have to write your own comparison function that knows how to deal with circular references.

Comment: Errors out on 3.4.2 on Ideone: https://ideone.com/GlBxXt

Answer (score 3):

You need to define what you mean by equal. Normally "equal" for dictionaries means 'all the key/value pairs are the "equal"'. If a dictionary has a reference to itself, this definition of equal may lead to a recursive definition, i.e. `a == b` iff `a == b`.

Take this simple example:

```
a = {}; a['item'] = a
b = {}; b['item'] = b
```

Are `a` and `b` equal? In order to know that, you need to first know if `a` and `b` are equal ...

You could create a special `equal` that looks something like this:

```
def equal(a, b, special=[]):
    if not isinstance(a, dict) or not isinstance(b, dict):
        return a == b

    special = special + [a, b]
    set_keys = set(a.keys())
    if set_keys != set(b.keys()):
        return False

    for key in set_keys:
        if any(a[key] is i for i in special):
            continue
        elif any(b[key] is i for i in special):
            continue
        elif not equal(a[key], b[key], special):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Your solution meets my example above, but what about cases such as `dict_1 = {'name': '1', 'children': [{'name': '2', 'parent': dict_1}]}`?  I'm hoping for a clean solution to fully iterating through various nested inalterables while avoiding circular loops.

Comment: This treats all recursive links as being equal, which doesn't make sense. For example, if we make a = {'x':a}, b = {'x':a, 'y':1}, and c = {'x':{'x':c}, 'y':1}, then this equal procedure says that b and c are equal, when they are not.  c has y's all the way down, but b does not.

Comment: Not knowing the specifics of the OPs full problem, I leave the implementation of the correct definition of "equal" up to OP (or another enthusiastic user). This example is meant to just show that you need to special case recursive references.

Comment: The most obvious meanings of "equal" would be "the same object" or "the same structure."  Assuming that all recursive links are "equal" to all other recursive links doesn't match any obvious meaning of the word "equal."

Comment: @Glomek the most obvious meaning of "equal" doesn't work, that's why we're in this situation in the first place :). Feel free to write another answer or edit my answer if you think I have not provided a useful response to the question.

Comment: I did.  See my proposal from yesterday.  My proposal is to keep two stacks, and to consider two recursive references to be equal if they both match at the same depth in their respective stacks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own comparison procedure that takes four arguments, two things to compare, and two stacks of dictionaries/lists (one for each thing being compared).

If either thing being compared is contained in the corresponding stack, return true if they are both in their own stack in the same position, and false otherwise.

Otherwise, if they are dictionaries, make sure that they have the same sets of keys (otherwise return false), and recurse on each value, adding the dictionaries to the two stacks.

If they are lists, make sure they are the same length (or return false) and recurse on each pair of members, adding the lists to the two stacks.

To get things started, call the recursive procedure with the things being compared and two empty stacks.  You can wrap this in another procedure that only takes two arguments.

```
def my_compare(a, b):
    return my_compare_helper(a, b, [], [])

def my_index(thing, stack):
    for i in range(len(stack)):
        if thing is stack[i]:
            return i
    return -1

def my_compare_helper(a, b, a_stack, b_stack):
    a_loc = my_index(a, a_stack)
    b_loc = my_index(b, b_stack)
    if a_loc != -1 or b_loc != -1:
        return a_loc == b_loc

    a_stack = [a] + a_stack
    b_stack = [b] + b_stack

    if isinstance(a, list):
        if not isinstance(b, list) or len(a) != len(b):
            return False
        for a_thing, b_thing in zip(a, b):
            if not my_compare_helper(a_thing, b_thing, a_stack, b_stack):
                return False
        return True

    if isinstance(a, dict):
        if not isinstance(b, dict):
            return False
        a_keys = sorted(a.keys())
        b_keys = sorted(b.keys())
        if a_keys != b_keys:    # Keys can't be recursive.
            return False
        for key in a_keys:
            if not my_compare_helper(a[key], b[key], a_stack, b_stack):
                return False
        return True

    return a == b
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, {}]
>>> a[1] = a
>>> a[2]['x'] = a
>>> b = [1, 2, {}]
>>> b[1] = b
>>> b[2]['x'] = b
>>> my_compare(a, b)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurred to me while I was doing something else that the pickle module handles recursive dictionaries and such. With that in mind this might work for you:

```
import copy
import cPickle

a = {}
a['self'] = a
a['list'] = [a, a, 0]

b = copy.deepcopy(a)
print(cPickle.dumps(a) == cPickle.dumps(b))
# True

b['self'] = copy.deepcopy(b)
print(cPickle.dumps(a) == cPickle.dumps(b))
# False
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import copy

child = {'name': 'child'}
parent_1 = {'name': 'parent', 'child': child}
child['parent'] = parent_1  # Create the circular reference

parent_2 = copy.copy(parent_1)
print(parent_1 == parent_2)
```

If you use `copy.copy` instead of `copy.deepcopy`, it runs without an error.

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for
>   compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or
>   class instances):
>
> • A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the
>   extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in
>   the original.
>
> • A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively,
>   inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

It is maybe a storage issue, that using deepcopy() forces actual recursion, whereas copy() can just check the references

Comment: While this does run without error, that is because both parents point to the same child object instead of two different but equivalent child objects. Using a shallow copy, `parent_1['child'] is parent_2['child']` returns `True`, when it should return `False`.  Effectively, after the first layer of depth, you are checking an object for equality against itself, and I need to check for equality against a different but equal object.